# Don't get the detailed output as shown in the tutorial when I launch a new node

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am new to the substrate and setting it up. I do not get the output fields as shown in the "Review the node messages displayed" section of the tutorial [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/#Start-the-first-blockchain-node) on how to launch a new node. I am following all the steps in the tutorial to launch the node, and my local blockchain is working fine and finalizing new nodes. The only issue is that I do not see the detailed output. I am pasting a screenshot below of what I see.

[image: Screenshot of initial output I see on launching a fresh node]

Comment: What version of Polkadot are you using? The latest version of the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/releases/tag/polkadot-v0.9.28) is using version 0.9.28 of Polkadot. You can look in the [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml) file to see what version you're using.